# How would I design my model in Rails where two attributes access the same class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, model

I've created a Team model that has the following attributes:

```
team_name
mascot
```

I now want to create a Game model with the following attributes:

```
game_date
away_team
away_team_score
home_team
home_team_score
```

I want both the away_team and home_team to be foreign keys to the Team class. I'm pretty sure I can't do this using away_team:references in my generator unless there is an option to specifically select the Team class. So if I create my model with away_team and home_team set as integers, how do I setup my has_many and belongs_to associations?

Answer (score 0):

[See the Rails 3 Associations Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_one-association-reference):

```
has_one :home_team, :class_name => "Team"
has_one :away_team, :class_name => "Team"
```

It's similar for the other relationships; you can override the convention-based... uh... conventions.

Comment: Shouldn't it be belongs_to instead of has_one ? since the Game model contains the foreign key...

Comment: @ErezRabih "It's similar for the other relationships [...]"

Comment: Ok, so are you saying my Game model has the following association: has_one :away_team, :class_name => "School", has_one :home_team, :class_name => "School"? How about my School model?